# How to see all comments for BitBucket.org pull request?

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request

Is there a way to see all comments on a [www.BitBucket.org](http://www.BitBucket.org) pull request?  It seems that the BitBucket.org web site automatically hides comments if code has been changed, so there's no easy way verify if the code has been fixed.  I'd like to be able to see the comments so I can check if the code has been fixed.  How do I do this?